# data not inserted into database in android

Tags: android

Hi In My Application I am displaying all the student names and roll no and I have one button If I click the save button I want store that records into another table.

Now My Problem is how to use the array for edit text's for student names and roll no.For Testing purpose I used single name for edit text for displaying single value of student name and roll no.By using toast while click the save button it's showing only student name,roll no showing empty.

Where I did mistake can any one please help me.

**Attend.java**

```
public class Attend extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    String data = "";
    TableLayout tl;
    TableRow tr;
    TextView studentName;
    EditText Firstname,stRoll;
    CheckBox present;
    String[] class_name, section_name;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    String student_name,roll;

    Button save;
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.maintable);

         save = (Button)findViewById(R.id.save); 
         Firstname  = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.studentname );
         Firstname.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         stRoll = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.rollnumber ); 
         stRoll.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //save.setText("Record Saved Sucessfully");
                student_name = Firstname.getText().toString();
                System.out.println(student_name);
                roll = stRoll.getText().toString();
                System.out.println(roll);
                Toast.makeText(
                        Attend.this,
                        "Result : " + "\nStudentName : " +student_name
                        + "\nRollno : " + roll,

                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("student_name",student_name));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("roll_no",roll));
                //nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("f3",v3));

                StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 
                data = DatabaseUtility.executeQueryPhp("save","");
                System.out.println(data);
            }    

        });

        String class_id = getIntent().getStringExtra("class_id");
        String section_id = getIntent().getStringExtra("section_id");
        Toast.makeText(
                this,
                "Result : " + "\nclassName : " + class_id + "\nSectionName : "
                        + section_id,

        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        final String queryString = "class_id=" + class_id + "&section_id="
                + section_id;
        /*String result = DatabaseUtility.executeQueryPhp("getStudent",
                queryString);*/

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                data = DatabaseUtility.executeQueryPhp("getStudent",queryString);
                System.out.println(data);

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        ArrayList<StudentDetails> users = parseJSON(data);
                        addData(users);
                    }
                });   
            }
        }).start();

    }
    public ArrayList<StudentDetails> parseJSON1(String result1) {
        ArrayList<StudentDetails> users = new ArrayList<StudentDetails>();
        try {
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result1);
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                StudentDetails user = new StudentDetails();

                user.setStudentname(json_data.getString("student_nme"));
                user.setRollno(json_data.getString("roll_no"));
                users.add(user);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }
        return users;
    }

    public ArrayList<StudentDetails> parseJSON(String result) {
        ArrayList<StudentDetails> users = new ArrayList<StudentDetails>();
        try {
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                StudentDetails user = new StudentDetails();
                // user.setId(json_data.getInt("class_name"));
                // user.setClass_id(json_data.getInt("section_name"));
                // user.setSection_id(json_data.getInt("section_id"));
                user.setStudentname(json_data.getString("first_name"));
                user.setRollno(json_data.getString("roll_no"));
                users.add(user);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }
        return users;
    }

    void addHeader() {

        tr = new TableRow(this);

        studentName = new TextView(this);           

        studentName.setText("StudentName");

        studentName.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        studentName.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        studentName.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        LinearLayout Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);

        Ll.addView(studentName, params);
        tr.addView((View) Ll);

        TextView RollNo = new TextView(this);
        RollNo.setText("RollNo");
        RollNo.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        RollNo.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        RollNo.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(0, 5, 5, 5);

        Ll.addView(RollNo, params);
        tr.addView((View) Ll);
        TextView Present = new TextView(this);
        Present.setText("Present");
        Present.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        Present.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        Present.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(0, 5, 5, 5);

        Ll.addView(Present, params);
        tr.addView((View) Ll);

        tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));                                
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes" })
    public void addData(ArrayList<StudentDetails> users) {

        addHeader();

        for (Iterator i = users.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {

            StudentDetails p = (StudentDetails) i.next();

            /** Create a TableRow dynamically **/
            tr = new TableRow(this);

            /** Creating a TextView to add to the row **/
            Firstname = new EditText(this);
            Firstname.setText(p.getStudentname());
            Firstname.setId(p.getId());
            Firstname.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            Firstname.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);

            LinearLayout Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(5, 2, 2, 2);

            Ll.addView(Firstname, params);
            tr.addView((View) Ll);

            EditText stRoll1= new EditText(this);
            stRoll1.setText(p.getRollno());
            stRoll1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            stRoll1.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);

            Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params1.setMargins(0, 3, 3, 3);

            Ll.addView(stRoll1, params1);
            tr.addView((View) Ll);
            CheckBox present = new CheckBox(this);

            present.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            present.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);

            Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(0, 3, 3, 3);

            Ll.addView(present, params);
            tr.addView((View) Ll);

            tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="none" >

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/maintable"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:stretchColumns="1,0,0" >



        </TableLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/save"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="save" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/studentname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/rollnumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/save"
        android:ems="10" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

** DatabaseUtility.java**

```
public static String executeQueryPhp(String phpScript,String queryString) {
        InputStream is = null;
        String line = null;
        String result = "";
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String url = "";
            if(queryString!=""){
                url= "http://10.0.2.2/android_connect/"+phpScript+".php?"+queryString;  
            }else{
                url = "http://10.0.2.2/android_connect/"+phpScript+".php"; 
            }
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            Log.e("Fail 1", "3");

            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            Log.e("Fail 1", "4");

            is = entity.getContent();
            Log.e("Pass 1", "connection success ");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());
            /*
             * Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid IP Address",
             * Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             */
            /* finish(); */
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Fail 2", e.toString());
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

php:

```
mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); 
mysql_select_db("login");
$student_name = !empty($_POST['student_name']) ? $_POST['student_name'] : $_GET['student_name'];
$roll_no = !empty($_POST['roll_no']) ? $_POST['roll_no'] : $_GET['roll_no'];
$query = "insert into save (student_name,roll_no) values('$student_name','$roll_no')";
$json_output = array();
if (!mysql_query($query )) {
  $json_output[] = mysql_errno() . ": ".mysql_error();
}else{
  $json_output[] = true;
}

print(json_encode($json_output));
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: Can you show us the xml for `R.layout.activity_main`?

Comment: Hi Pedro Oliveira added xml file

Comment: If you're setting the visibility of the edittexts to GONE how are you editing it's content?

Comment: display format it's displaying I am using that editText Box name Xml edittext I don't want to display at the view time for that I wrote GONE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your addData you're creating a new EditBox for your rollno instead of using the one that you defined like you do with Firstname. My sugestion would be to change

```
EditText stRoll1=
```

to

```
stRoll
```

instead as well as all stRoll1 to stRoll.

Comment: Now I have 3 records name1,roll1 and name2,roll2 and name3,roll3 I want to store all the records to database

Comment: but data not inserted into database

Comment: I suggest you ask another question since this one has been answered ;)

Comment: main title I mentioned Data not inserted into database

Comment: That is only my question

Comment: First of all you say "save on a table" but there is no mention of the dabatase at all. You say "now my problem is" and as far as I know that problem is solved. Secondly as far as I know you're trying to save it on a "database" that's not your device. You call `data = DatabaseUtility.executeQueryPhp("save","");` and you pass no data as the second parameter. We can't guess what the server is supposed to receive here. Next time you ask a question make sure the question is not only in the title but on the description itself ;)

Comment: Just Now added  DatabaseUtility.java file In that passing url with querry string without querry string

Comment: If you pass the querystring empty how is the server supposed to know what to save?

Comment: can you please checkout My php file

Comment: I guess your query string will have to be something like `"student_name=" + student_name+ "&roll_no=" + roll` and pass it on `DatabaseUtility.executeQueryPhp("save",querystring);`

Comment: At A time how to save all the 3 records means what i have to do

Comment: Create a queryString for each user and execute `DatabaseUtility.executeQueryPhp("save",queryString);` for each one

Comment: student names->ram,raghu,k and rollno->1,2,3 for student names these are roll no means querry string same for all these record